# Updating a single data in a switch case

Tags: php

I have a case in a switch, that i'm using to update some data (questions). The problem is that if i edit a question and click submit, nothing happens.. However when i edit all the questions the same, they're updated into my database. Anyway to make the update single per question. So if i edit one data and click submit it is upgraded without having to upgrade everything else.

```
case 'Addquiz':
    $sql = "SELECT questiontext,type FROM questioninfo ORDER BY type DESC ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $selectedtable  = "<form method='post' action=''>\n";
    $selectedtable .= "<table class='sortable'>\n<tr><th>Question</th><th>Type</th></tr>\n";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $selectedtable .= "<tr><td><input type='text' name='QuestionText' value='".$row['questiontext']."'></td><td>$row[1]</td></tr>\n";
    }

    $selectedtable .= "</table>\n"; 
    $selectedtable .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>\n";
    $selectedtable .= "<input type='submit' name='addquestion' value='Add Question' style='width:140px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>\n";
    $selectedtable .= "</form>\n";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        $questiontext = $_POST['QuestionText'];

        $sql1="SELECT questiontext FROM questioninfo";

        if($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
            $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }

        if($rowcount==0) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO questioninfo (questiontext) VALUES('$questiontext')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        } else {
            $sql2 = "UPDATE questioninfo SET questiontext = '$questiontext'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Your input boxes, inside your loop, have the same 'name' field.  Therefore, only the last 'name' value will be accessible once submitted.

Comment: @MaggsWeb any possible solution?

Comment: @MaggsWeb thank you !!

Comment: Also be aware of SQL injection.. if its not a term your familiar with, worth a google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your `input` tag inside your loop to have a dynamic name, using the rowID from your query result.

```
<input type='text' name='QuestionText[$row[id]]' value='".$row['questiontext']."'>
.....................................^        ^
```

This will then submit an 'array' of QuestionText elements, each with the row ID as the 'key' and the inputted text as the 'value'

Then, after submission of the form, loop through $_POST['QuestionText'] and process each one in turn, something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['QuestionText'] as $key => $value){

    // update row $key with $value

}
```

I can't see how you would ever need the `insert` query, as they all come from the db originally.

Comment: Agreed, generate a unique name per input/entry or use an array.. On the submission side either submit the array of inputs or have a common class that will be used as a method to post them. This allows you to have a insert button that will create a new input on the page for additions as well as editing.

Comment: @MaggsWeb are you available?

Comment: @MaggsWeb i'm having problems applying your solution

Comment: Is it possible for a couple of minutes of your time?

Comment: @MaggsWeb i tried applying your solution, but couldn't get it to work, so i tried creating a counter but nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87269/discussion-between-dan-and-maggsweb).